# Rails newbie - how to structure a calendar generating app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, icalendar

I'm working on a service to provide our students and faculty with one single calendar (ICS subscription) of their academic dates (start and end of term & exam periods, class dates and times, exam dates and times, etc). I'm a Ruby and Rails newbie; we're starting to work more with it here so I figured this would be a good learning opportunity. I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure and model (if at all) certain parts of the app.

The app is conceptually pretty basic:

- User logs in and a user record is created for them. A UUID is generated and stored on the user's record; it's used to generate their ICS URL (http://myservice.foo/feeds/johndoe_ce4970706f320130588b109add5c7cb0.ics).
- When the user requests their ICS file (through the above URL), I need to query a bunch of different systems in order to get information in order to build a calendar:

  - The Student Information System (SIS) contains the user's schedule (e.g. johndoe is taking ENGL 100 on MWF from 10:30 - 11:20). I need to parse this data and create events.
  - Our online learning management system, Canvas, provides a calendar of assignments for courses contained inside it. It's accessible as an ICS file, so I need to pull down that file, parse it and include it in the "master" calendar that my app will generate.
  - Instructors can specify an additional ICS URL for their course so that they can include arbitrary events not provided by either of the two above sources. Like the Canvas calendar, I need to download and parse that ICS.

I have the first part working; I can log in through our single sign-on system (CAS) and a user record is created with a generated UUID. I'm not sure how to handle the second part, though. I don't need to store much permanent data; basically, I only need to keep around the user record (which contains their username, the generated UUID, and some access tokens for the Canvas LMS). The feed will be generated the first time it's requested, cached for some period (and regenerated on-demand when needed).

Where should I be putting the parsing and generating code? I'd like it to be somewhat modular as I expect that we'd be adding other data sources as they crop up. Should I be creating calendar and event models if I'm not actually persisting that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need to create an empty model for interaction with 3rd party services. I had a similar problem, where I needed to receive data from an external service and wanted it to be modular. One of recommended solutions I found was to create a class (that handles business logic of the interaction with the external service) in the "lib" folder under the root directory of your rails project.

It later can be required in your controller and used to receive date from the third party service. Or if you want it autoloaded, then you can add path to lib directory in your application.rb file under config.autoload_paths setting.

Comment: Is there a difference between putting stuff in /lib and in /app/services? I've seen it done both ways.

Comment: As of Rails 3 classes in "lib" folder are not autoloaded and must be required, but classes in "/app/services" will be autoloaded automatically. If you need your service class only in single controller, then it is safer to put it in the "lib" folder and require it only in that controller.